# How to close DialogBox programmatically

Tags: c#

I create a simple form that pops up a dialog box when you run it, but i cannot close it programmatically.
Can anyone help me with that?

```
Label lb = new Label();
Form frm = new Form();
lb.Left = 100;
lb.Top = 44;
frm.Controls.Add(lb);
frm.ShowDialog();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

After ..Sleep(2000) i want it to close.
I tried:

```
 frm.close();frm.dispose();frm.visible = false;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` will start AFTER you will close frm. You must start new thread before opening frm. And do sleep, close... in that thread

Comment: The best way is doing it in your `frm` if it's going to be just after some time

Comment: I know i can do it with Show(), but i need it with showDialog().
In my programm Show() crashes the system, but dialog not

Comment: Mark, if you want to close your dialog after some time, close it in your dialog. If the case is different, tell us.

Comment: As @Pikoh comments, why not put a timer inside your dialog and let close itself.

Comment: Can you show me an example to close the showdialogbox()  after some time?

Comment: See my answer Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To close any form after a specific time you can use an extension method

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static async Task CloseAfterDelay(this Form form, int millisecondsDelay )
    {
        await Task.Delay( millisecondsDelay );
        form.Close();
    }
}
```

and call it **before** you show the form

```
Label lb = new Label();
Form frm = new Form();
lb.Left = 100;
lb.Top = 44;
frm.Controls.Add(lb);

frm.CloseAfterDelay( 2000 );

frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer, it helped me. I wanna ask if you can provide me a sample code that dialogbox will close only when i press a button.Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like this inside you form class:

```
protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Close();
}
```

Inside the `OnLoad` method run a task that wait 2000 ms and close the form.

Comment: Just to clarify, this code needs .net 4.5 if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `frm.ShowDialog();` use `frm.Show();`

`ShowDialog()` will wait for the dialog to close then continue the code.

Edited:

```
        Label lb = new Label();
        Form frm = new Form();
        lb.Left = 100;
        lb.Top = 44;
        frm.Controls.Add(lb);

        frm.Load += delegate (object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(p =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                Action action = frm.Close;
                Invoke(action);
            });
            thread.Start();
        };
        frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I really need it with ShowDialog() cause in my program the show method crashes it

Comment: You should mention that in your question that you have tried `Show()` and it crashes.

Comment: Holy mother, thank you so much. I was tearing my hair out. This tutorial I was following was using `ShowDialog`. I didn't realize there was a `Show`
https://theitbros.com/powershell-gui-for-scripts/

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following way. May be this is not the more appropriate way. But I think it will solve your issue:

```
        Label lb = new Label();
        Form frm = new Form();

        frm.Shown += Frm_Shown;

        lb.Left = 100;
        lb.Top = 44;
        frm.Controls.Add(lb);
        var result = frm.ShowDialog();   

    private void Frm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = (Form)sender;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        frm.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        frm.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` will run on the main thread and make application unresponsive for the duration of the sleep

Answer (score 2):

[ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) will display the form as a modal dialog. That means, the call will wait until the form was closed. That again means your `Thread.Sleep()` will be executed after the form was already closed.

The non-modal version would be [Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx), but that can cause issues, because during the Sleep, the UI will not be updated, so it appears frozen. You would need to keep the message loop alive.

```
for (int i=1; i<40; i++)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

You should understand the [consequences of DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents) when you do that. IMHO the cleaner approach would be a timer on the form as mentioned by [@Pikoh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384661/4136325)

Also note the code that follows

```
frm.close();frm.dispose();frm.visible = false;
```

After Dispose() you should not access the form any more, because it's already destroyed. Maybe that caused the crash.

Answer (score 1):

To close your dialog after some time, you must add a timer in your dialog form,something like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer tim = new Timer();
    tim.Interval = 2000;
    tim.Tick += new EventHandler(tim_Tick);
    tim.Enabled = true;
}

void tim_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

You can add your timer in your `Form_Load` or in your form's constructor.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, it helped me. I wanna ask if you can provide me a sample code that dialogbox will close only when i press a button.Is that possible?